# Pass parameter to a jquery function

Tags: jquery, function, parameters

I know that doing this is possible:

```
$(document).ready(testing);

function testing(){
    alert('hellow world!');
}
```

But how would I make something like this work where I want to pass a variable to the function:

```
 $(document).ready(testing('hey world!'));

function testing(message){
    alert(message);
}
```

Comment: That's not a jQuery function, it is simply a JavaScript function within the scope of a jQuery wrapper.

Comment: In what weird case would you want this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Function.prototype.bind` but it come with some disadvantages like losing the `this` reference or the `Event` object.

```
$(document).ready(testing.bind(null, 'message')); //First parameter == this;

function testing(msg){
    alert(msg); //Alert message
}
```

or you can do it like this :

```
$(document).ready(testing.bind('message'));

function testing(){
    alert(this); //Alert message
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KedKq/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  testing('hey world!'));
});

function testing(message){
    alert(message);
}
```